# keyboard up- down-arrowkeys do not respond from browser address bar

Tags: upgrade

If on the address bar, the up and down arrow keys don't respond neither in Firefox nor Chromium.
This problem started after an upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not working in Firefox, but at least with the Chromium update that was released on the 23th of September 2014, it's working.
Chromium Version 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 14.04 (281580) (64-bit)